# When visualizing data that has <1 or <5 ppm how do you display this?

Tags: visualization, data

I have some data (parts per million) where some of it is 1 or greater than one (but has an actual number.) However, some of the data simply lists "<1" ppm.

What is a good way to visualize this in a graph?

Should I pick an arbitrary decimal less than one, so that it can be shown on the graph? I feel setting it to zero would not be right either, as they went to the extent of listing it, so it must be significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a univariate plot?  If so, just bin the data and toss it into the lowest bin.

Comment: It is not. Currently I have it in histograms- but anything that shows as a <1 shows up as zero. (Excel Pivot Tables)

Comment: A histogram is a univariate plot.  A scatterplot is a bivariate plot.  You could make a bar chart where all the <1's are in a bin.

Comment: Oh, I did not realize. And that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Usually a regulator will require that you use half of the "<" number.

the < means that the analysis measured ZERO of whatever was being measured but there is usually a lower limit of reading (a test might not be able to measure below say 5ppm so if they measure a Zero all they can really say is that the result must have been <5ppm because they couldn't measure anything.
So what do you repot....5 ? or Zero? ....no you report 2.5ppm. halfway between the limit of reading and zero.